# Android game causing phone to lock up

Tags: java, android, debugging, freeze

So I'm creating a game for this game competition at my college. I am extending a surfaceview and basically just moving drawables around on a screen. I recently just changed some pictures to a more updated picture. Now when I press the home button (or the back button) my phone will completely lock up and I will have to pull my battery out to restart it.

I have also tested this with other phones and their phones will lock up. Is there anything that could cause this to happen?

Comment: The likely culprits are the `onPause`, `onStop` or `onDestroy` methods of your Activity. Make sure nothing in them blocks or does heavy computation or file I/O.

Comment: This is my first time using this site, so sorry if I'm not descriptive enough. The way I have my game to pause is using the onWindowFocusChanged() method in the surfaceview class. When it loses focus, i set the thread = null. Then when it gets focus again, i set the thread equal to a new thread and it using the instance variables that i created outside of the thread to create the thread so it has the same state when it was set to null. I do not change the default onPause(), onStop(), or onDestroy() in the activity.

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting messages about ANRs in the log? If so, try this: execute the command (on your computer) `adb pull /data/anr/traces.txt` -- this will contain stack traces for anything running when the system reported the ANR. From here, you can examine the stack traces of your program, and hopefully find the place where things are getting stuck and freezing everything.

If there's nothing in /data/tanr/traces.txt, you can try the command `adb bugreport` which will return just about every piece of information it can (including stack traces for all running processes).

These traces are helpful when you get into a frozen state such as this.

Comment: in logcat, I am getting repeated "request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol. Then every few lines I get a tag "dalvikvm" with a message "GC_FOR_MALLOC freed: (some big number) objects / (number) bytes in 130ms"

Comment: Examining the stacks of the threads in the running process will probably be more helpful than logcat, at this point.